# Strapi and Nuxt/Vue Accessing Image URL

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, strapi

I am currently getting below json from my strapi model. I have a featured_image column where I upload image.

Problem faced currently is I am unable to access the image url. It says no url property of undefined.

I guess this is happening because image column is not a object it acts as normal string.

Json from Strapi:

https://api.myjson.com/bins/1fgx71
or 
http://myjson.com/1fgx71

Nuxt Code:

```
  <v-img :src="post.post_featured_image"></v-img>
```

I am stuck at this.

This does have all the elements relate to image, but I am unable to get url from it. Tried below methods.

```
post.post_featured_image.url
post.post_featured_image['url']
post.post_featured_image[0].url
post.post_featured_image[0]['url']
```

like this several things i tried still I am unable to get the image url to get it working

Answer (score 1):

The json that is accessible from the url above is showing an array of posts!
So I guess that in your case you're going to be able to access the image of the first post using this:

`post[0].post_featured_image.url`

Comment: Thank you for you response. in my case post is single object as the post used in vue is actually after using v-for like post in posts

Comment: Ok I got the answer. Actually it was failing because post 2 doesn't have the post_featurd_image tag so it was actually failing to display the second record.

Answer (score 1):

So Basically it requires a if condition so it doesn't fail when it does not find the respective tag.

```
<v-responsive v-if="post.post_featured_image">
   <v-img :src="post.post_featured_image.url"></v-img>
</v-responsive>
```